# How to install the Eclipse plugin for Symfony 2?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, symfony

I want to install the Eclipse plugin for Symfony 2. But I'm stuck at the start.

I'm following the guide at http://pulse00.github.com/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/.

> Prerequisites
>
> At the current stage the Symfony Eclipse Plugin requires a nightly
>   build of the PHP Development Tools (PDT), as there have been some
>   changes to the way extenders can hook into PDT. This nightly build can
>   be downloaded as a build artifact from the eclipse continuous
>   integration site. You'll need to download a file called
>   pdt-Update-N[TIMESTAMP]>.zip by clicking the latest build in the build
>   history -> Build artifacts -> build/N[TIMESTAMP] .

So, I visited the "eclipse continuous integration site" at https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/cbi-pdt-3.0-indigo/ but I couldnt find the file they said: pdt-Update-N[TIMESTAMP].

I just can't find it there. I tried downloading some other files but don't know what to do with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same issue. I found this [link](http://www.lafermeduweb.net/tutorial/installer-et-configurer-symfony-eclipse-plugin-pour-symfony2-p93.html) which is in french, but I was able to gleam the following steps:

1. Go [here](https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/cbi-pdt-3.0-indigo/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/)
2. Where it says "build / N0000000000000", click the N00000000000
3. Then look in the file list near the bottom for the archive.

Answer (score 5):

@Tool no nightly-build of PDT is needed anymore, simply add the updatesite and install the plugin: http://symfony.dubture.com/installation/

Answer (score 2):

I found this post was particularly helpful for me

http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/2011/11/07/how-to-build-a-great-eclipse-environment-for-symfony2-development/

As noted in the installation instructions for the Symfony2 Eclipse plugin on Github

https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin#readme

just add the update site to your available software sites (Help > Install new software > Add)

http://p2.dubture.com